# Finding the controller that called my controller; or traversing the Controller/Action stack

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Html.RenderAction, in ASP.NET MVC (futures), to display modules on different pages.
I want the modules to be aware of which page they belong to (for settings and logging purposes).

Is there a way to get the Controller/Action - stack, on the current controller?

I found on the Controller base something called DescriptorCache under ActionInvoker and that has something called Cache wich has that info, however I do not have access to that in the Controller because it's defined as private.

Appreciate your help
:m

Comment: IMO if you do this you will break the MVC pattern as view will be aware of the controller

Answer (score 1):

Can you? Yeah. Should you? Hell no. If you need to conditionally render, *put the data into the view's model.* Don't try to use the call stack as part of your view model!

Comment: Well, the thing is that I do not want to use this information in the view itself. I am talking about the controller for the "sub-view" that gets called by the Html.RenderAction method.
The situation is as follows; I have moduels that get placed on different pages, then the modules need to know what page they belong to.
I do know that this info can be put into the view model for the modules, but I want to make them as self contained as possible and therefore have them pick up where they are placed.